# JSON Property Undefined even thought the variable containing the Data is populated with a JSON object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

I am trying to receive a MongoDB document from my database through a get request. I have tested the URL via Postman and is returning the document as expected. This has made me aware that the issue is in the frontend and not the Server.
When I do the same via my frontend, it retrieves the data, and is stored in the variable **res** and assigned to **this.englishteam** so it can be accessed outside the function scope of GetSingleEnglishTeam.

```
public teamenglish!:EnglishTeam;

GetSingleEnglishTeam(_id: string) {
    this.englishTeamService.GetSingleEnglishTeam(_id).subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log("The team: "+ res);
      this.teamenglish = res;
      //  console.log(this.teamenglish);

    })
  }
```

However, when I try to access the **ClubName** stored in **teamenglish** I get an undefined error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ClubName' of undefined
> at ClubHonoursComponent_Template (club-honours.component.html:9)

**Club-honours.component.html**

```
 <div class="row">
<div class="column">
  <div class="PremierLeagues" >
    {{teamenglish.ClubName}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**Get Request to the Server**

```
GetSingleEnglishTeam(_id: string){
console.log( "ID is "+_id);

return this.http.get<EnglishTeam>('http://localhost:3000/api/getTeamEn/' + `${_id}`);
}
```

When I console log the variable containing the JSON object I get [Object Object].

What I want to do is be able to send a getOne request to the server and the server to return the single document. Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the template is initialised before `teamenglish` variable could be set in callback of `subscribe`.

You can solve this by 3 methods -

1.) In your template file use **Safe navigation operator** `(?)`  i.e. -

```
{{teamenglish?.ClubName}}
```

2.) Use *ngIf on container div to only render itself if `teamenglish` is available to use (which will be available to use once your observable callback sets it to `teamenglish` i.e. -

```
 <div *ngIf="teamenglish" class="PremierLeagues" >
    {{teamenglish.ClubName}}
  </div>
```

3.) Use `async` pipe in your template to automatically handle the subscription and value resolution i.e.

In your `ts` file, assign the observale to a variable like -

```
const obs = this.englishTeamService.GetSingleEnglishTeam(_id)
```

Then in your template file -

```
{{obs | async | json}}
```

Comment: I have tried both, and they stop the undefined error, thank you. However, the data mapped to that variable is not displayed in the HTML.

Comment: I have done so and I can see both [Object Object] and when I stringify "res" I can see the entire document data.

Comment: Try ```{{teamenglish | json}}``` in your html and see what happens. 
PS: Wrap it in ```*ngIf```

Comment: It outputs the entire JSON document Data. It is definitely there.

Comment: Does it have the ```ClubName``` property ?

Comment: It does. Spelled exactly the same.

Comment: Snippet of the JSON 
 
 
 
 "LeagueTitles":19,"EUCup":6,"ClubWorldCups":1,"FaCups":7,"LeagueCups":"8","UEFACups":3,"UEFASuperCups":4,"CharityShields":15},"_id":"609993fc87ff34b58723ce9e","ClubName":"Chelsea FC"}}

Comment: Also in your observable callback can you try - 
```if (res.hasOwnProperty("ClubName")){
    console.log(res.ClubName);             
} ```

Comment: Got the problem from your pastebin. The problem is -
```Clubname``` property doesn't exist on ```res```, but it exists on ```res.Team``` i.e. ```res.Team.Clubname```

Comment: You absolute legend. Much appreciated!!!! ive got a property doesnt exist error now, but i will get around that!